# WP8 Universal Volume Control enable fast forward/rewind

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

Im working on a music player that is based on this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) but having difficulty defining which of the controls to have enabled, by default it appears with next/previous controls by i needed to have fast forward and rewind instead, looking through the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh203123%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and looking at the constructor there is a reference to the [EnabledPlayerControls Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.enabledplayercontrols%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

> This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values.

but there is no sample code, and i don't know how to do it.

Could someone show me how to do it?

the AudioTrack is being initialised like this

*(Just showing one for the sake of example)*

```
private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
{
new AudioTrack(new Uri("Kalimba.mp3", UriKind.Relative), 
                "Kalimba", 
                "Mr. Scruff", 
                "Ninja Tuna", 
                null, null, EnabledPlayerControls.???)
};
```

on *???* it only allows me to select one option (including all, but i only want fast forward and rewind.

I've done some searches but could not find an answer, if someone could show me how to do it or direct me to an example, I would appreciate.

Thanks,
Bob.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh bumper it was actually easier than i thought, i guess i just had a blank moment (i was using comma instead of |), below it the sample code, hope it helps someone.

```
private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
{
  new AudioTrack(new Uri("Kalimba.mp3", UriKind.Relative), 
            "Kalimba", 
            "Mr. Scruff", 
            "Ninja Tuna", 
            null, null, EnabledPlayerControls.Pause | EnabledPlayerControls.Rewind | EnabledPlayerControls.FastForward)
};
```